# Dúvida como exibir arvore binária por largura?

Tags: c++, árvore-binária

Bom para usar esse método de **exibir** precisa de uma fila ai tudo certo, eu tentei esta lógica funcionou até o **terceiro nível da arvore**.

```
bool marcador = true;
void buscaLargura(No *raiz)
{

   if(raiz != NULL)
   {
        if (marcador == true)
        {
            Enqueve(raiz->Elemento);
        }


       if (raiz->Esq != NULL)
       {
           Enqueve(raiz->Esq->Elemento);
       }
        if(raiz->Dir != NULL)
       {
           Enqueve(raiz->Dir->Elemento);
       }
        marcador= false;
        buscaLargura(raiz->Esq);
        buscaLargura(raiz->Dir);


   }

}
```

Comment: * exibir usando busca em largura, ficou incompleto no comentário da recompensa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O que pretendes, como o nome da tua função indica, pode ser obtido usando o algoritmo de travessia [Breadth-first search (BFS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) ou [Pesquisa em Largura](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busca_em_largura)

Para a seguinte árvore binária

```
                 15
               /    \
             6       20
           /   \       \  
         3      7       22
       /   \     \        \
     2       5     8       25
   /       /             /     
 1       4             23
```

Assumo que o resultado desejado seja:

```
15 6 20 3 7 22 2 5 8 25 1 4 23
```

Aqui fica uma possível definição para uma árvore binária (de procura) e uma versão iterativa para fazer visualização da árvore.

```
#include<queue>
#include<iostream>   

class ArvoreB {
protected:
    struct no {
            no *esquerda;  
            no *direita; 
            int v;   

            no() {}
            no( 
               int v,
               no *l = nullptr,
               no *r = nullptr)
             : esquerda(l), direita(r), v(v) {}
    };

    no* raiz_;      
    size_t numElementos_;    

public:
    ArvoreB(): raiz_(nullptr), numElementos_(0) {}

    void inserir(int v) {
        no *novoNo = new no(v);
            no *pai = nullptr;

        if(!raiz_) {
            raiz_ = novoNo;
            ++numElementos_;
            return;
        }
        no* actual = raiz_;

        while(actual) {
            pai = actual;
            actual = novoNo->v > actual->v ? actual->direita : actual->esquerda;
        }

        if(novoNo->v < pai->v) {
            pai->esquerda = novoNo;
        }
        else {
            pai->direita = novoNo;
        }
        ++numElementos_;
    }

    void inserir(std::vector<int> v) {
        for(std::vector<int>::iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it) {
            inserir(*it); 
        }
    }

    void buscaLargura() {      
        std::queue<no*> q;
        q.push(raiz_);  

        while (q.size() > 0)
        {
            no* n = q.front();
            q.pop();
            std::cout << n->v << " ";

            if (n->esquerda !=nullptr) {
                    q.push(n->esquerda);
            }
            if (n->direita !=nullptr) {
                q.push(n->direita);
            }
        }

        std::cout << std::endl;
    }   

    void mostraArvore() {
        std::queue<no*> nivelActual, nivelSeguinte;
        nivelActual.push(raiz_);
        while(!nivelActual.empty()) {
            no* noActual = nivelActual.front();
            nivelActual.pop();

            if(noActual) {
                std::cout << noActual->v << " ";
                nivelSeguinte.push(noActual->esquerda);
                nivelSeguinte.push(noActual->direita);
            }
            if(nivelActual.empty()) {
                std::cout << std::endl;
                swap(nivelActual, nivelSeguinte);
            }
        }
    }

};
```

Vamos então testar

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::vector<int> v = {15, 6, 3, 7, 2, 5, 8, 1, 4, 20, 22, 25, 23};
    BTree t;
    t.inserir(v);

    //t.inserir(15);
    //t.inserir(6);
    //t.inserir(3);
    //t.inserir(7);
    //t.inserir(2);
    //t.inserir(5);
    //t.inserir(8);
    //t.inserir(1);
    //t.inserir(4);
    //t.inserir(20);
    //t.inserir(22);
    //t.inserir(25);
    //t.inserir(23);

    t.buscaLargura();

    t.mostraArvore();
    return 0;
}
```

O resultado da função `bfs` será:

```
15 6 20 3 7 22 2 5 8 25 1 4 23
```

A função `mostraArvore` cria uma linha diferente para cada nível

```
15 
6 20 
3 7 22 
2 5 8 25 
1 4 23
```

Edição:

- Adicionar versão alternativa do método inserir. Esta verão permite recebe como um parâmetro um std::vector

Comment: -1. Sua resposta usa desnecessariamente palavras em inglês (output, display) usa o termo Breadth-first Search quando poderia usar "Busca em largura" (e linkar para um texto em português também não faria mal) e seu código está todo em inglês, tornando-o potencialmente indecifrável para os leitores, enquanto o código do OP está em português. Estamos no SO em português. Vamos falar nossa língua?

Comment: Muito obrigado pelo comentário @Pablo. Alterei de acordo com a sua sugestão.

Comment: Eu que agradeço, @bruno. +1. :)

Comment: @bruno agradeço por sua resposta, mas eu precisava de uma função busca largura usando um fila, me parece que seu código é orientado objeto, é uma parte que não tenho muito conhecimento preciso de algo mais simples como eu tentei fazer.

Comment: Rodolfo, tanto a função buscaLargura como a função mostraArvore usam uma fila (queue). Se não quiser usar a std::queue pode substituir por uma fila criada por você.

Comment: @bruno essa fila  já vem pronta?

Comment: @Rodolfo, sim, já vem pronta. Mas nada impede de usar uma fila criada por você. Basta substituir a linha std::queue<no *> pela sua fila.

Comment: @bruno conseguir usar com minha fila tudo certo fiz ela enfileirar tipo No funcionado,  bom minha arvore era de inteiro, agora ela é um tipo que crie com struct , mas a fila da erro agora    error: 'No' does not name a type

Comment: Provavelmente tens que copiar a definição do tipo "No" para o mesmo ficheiro da tua Fila.